# MySQL: Virtual Column based on JSON boolean value - convert boolean to tinyint possible?

Tags: mysql, json

I have a table with a json field `attributes` and a virtual tinyint (boolean) column `flights` with the following configuration:

`JSON_UNQUOTE(attributes->"$.flights")`

The `flights` property in the json field is a "real" boolean, eg. `true`. When adding this property to the json field MySQL returns `Incorrect integer value: 'true' for column 'flights' at row 1` which is understandable.

My question is if it's possible to change the configuration for the virtual column so that it converts the boolean to the correct integer value on the fly?

Comment: Show us a sample of the JSON with a boolean in it.  We need to see whether the "true" is quoted or not.  Also, what process created the JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I found the solution myself after struggling through it. If anyone is looking for a similar answer - this is how I do it:

`CAST(attributes->"$.flights" as signed int)`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> WITH cte AS (
>     SELECT CAST('{"flights":true}' AS JSON) attributes
>     UNION ALL
>     SELECT '{"flights":false}'
> )
> SELECT JSON_PRETTY(attributes), 
>        attributes->'$.flights' + 0
> FROM cte
> ```
>
> | JSON_PRETTY(attributes) | attributes->'$.flights' + 0 |
> | --- | --- |
> | {"flights": true} | 1 |
> | {"flights": false} | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ae85a9ea89c91c1d6f21693c0172304c)*